# Can CiviCRM work by itself (e.g. without Drupal)?

Tags: drupal

I have CiviCRM connected with Drupal to sync users and other information. I am planning to make a new website to replace Drupal, perhaps without having it connected to CiviCRM.

Can CiviCRM work by itself? Can I "disconnect" it from Drupal and have it run alone?

Answer (score 7):

There is a paid service you can use for this, if you wish to go that route:
[CiviDesk](https://www.cividesk.com) offers a hosted standalone version of CiviCRM you can subscribe to.  Nicolas from CiviDesk has expressed interest in other people using standalone Civi, so you may want to talk to him. You can download the code for standalone Civi [here](https://github.com/cividesk/civicrm-core), but of course this isn't supported by the core team.

Answer (score 6):

It used to be possible (using openid as a login system). There is a member of the community that is (or was until a recent version) using it.

However, consider this unsupported, so you might be fighting on your own with bugs no one will be able to help you with.

I'm often in your case for clients, what I do is a minimal drupal that only does deal with theme and login that lives on a separate subdomain than the main site.

Answer (score 2):

As Lisbeth points out, CiviDesk maintains a standalone version - but this isn't supported by the core team.  Nevertheless, Nicolas from CiviDesk has expressed interest in other people using standalone Civi, so you may want to talk to him.  Download a copy [here](https://github.com/cividesk/civicrm-core).

Comment: Since Lizbeth already mentioned CiviDesk, I would suggest deleting this answer, upvoting hers, and adding your text as a comment.

Comment: @choster as far as I can tell SE encourages multiple answers per question even if they are similar. Something to discuss in more detail on meta.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible. You can, however, run Civi with a CMS separately from your main website. For instance, if www.example.com is your (non-Drupal) website, you could still run Civi on a minimal Drupal at http://civicrm.example.com/ or http://www.example.com/mycrmsubdirectory/ .

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You could use Wordpress or Joomla.

CiviCRM requires a CMS. The standalonde version was discontinued some years back.